Getting JSON field in LWC and perform some operations on it
Context:
I have a custom object CustomObj with a Long Text Area field (sample_field) that stores a JSON. I need to retrieve this field's value in an LWC (Lightning Web Component) and perform operations based on the key-value pairs inside the JSON.
What I’ve considered so far:

Aura-enabled method: Create an Aura-enabled Apex method to fetch the sample_field value and parse the JSON in the LWC.
getRecords wire adapter: Using the getRecords wire adapter to retrieve the field value.

Questions:
Between the two options above, which is preferred for better performance or simplicity, considering that the field value is updated by a scheduled job?
Any alternative solutions or suggestions for handling this type of scenario?
The field value is updated via running a schedule job.

Please note that if you need just one record, you should prefer getRecord wire adapter over getRecords. Anyway to use those adapters, you need the record Id(s), you cannot filter the query by a custom expression, therefore this should be the criteria to choose them over an Apex method.
If the LWC knows the Ids of the records, I would use the wire adapter so I won't have to write a new Apex method, otherwise, if the query that retrieves the records has a WHERE clause more complex than WHERE Id = :recordId, you need either an Apex method or the graphQL wire adapter.
Since the field is updated via Apex (the scheduled job), the LDS cache is not invalidated, so no matter what you will choose to retrieve the record (a wire adapter or an Apex method), it won't automatically refresh the value after an update.
If you need this feature, the scheduled job could publish a platform event after the update and the LWC could use the lightning/empApi module for subscribing to it. In this scenario I would go for an Apex method to retrieve the records, since the use of refreshApex to refresh data from non-Apex wire adapters is deprecated (docs)

Thank you for the detailed explanation @RubenDG.
